# Simple HTTP client and server in python but client making atleast 50 request simultaneously with different IP address for each request

Tags: python-2.7

I want to know how , HTTP CLIENT making 100 REQUEST to server at same time but with different IP address for each request or with range of **IP ADDRESSES**, code in python or using a CURL function in code by configuring different IP Addresses or range of IP Addresses

Please help me editing the code to make several request to sever using different IP address requesting for a Html or web page on server and reading it contents.

Luckily, python provide us an HTTP server module, it's called BaseHTTPServer. We use two classes from this module, namely BaseHTTPRequestHandler and HTTPServer. We also need to use os module to access file in your system.

First, we need to import those modules

```
#!/usr/bin/env python



from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os
```

Next, write a custom class namely KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler that implement BaseHTTPRequestHandler.

```
#Create custom HTTPRequestHandler class
class KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
```

I just implement GET command from HTTP. To do that, we need to override do_GET() function. Our objective is to request an HTML file from server using our client (explained int the next step). Script inside do_GET() function is written to handle our objective

```
#handle GET command
def do_GET(self):
    rootdir = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/' #file location
    try:
        if self.path.endswith('.html'):
            f = open(rootdir + self.path) #open requested file


        #send code 200 response
        self.send_response(200)

        #send header first
        self.send_header('Content-type','text-html')
        self.end_headers()

        #send file content to client
        self.wfile.write(f.read())
        f.close()
        return

except IOError:
    self.send_error(404, 'file not found')
```

Finally, add following script to run the server

```
def run():
    print('http server is starting...')


#ip and port of servr
#by default http server port is 80
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler)
print('http server is running...')
httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Save it and name it whatever you want (e.g, kodefun-httpserver.py). Here is the complete script of http server:

```
kodefun-httpserver.py


#!/usr/bin/env python

from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import os

#Create custom HTTPRequestHandler class
class KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

        #handle GET command
        def do_GET(self):
                rootdir = 'c:/xampp/htdocs/' #file location
                try:
                        if self.path.endswith('.html'):
                                f = open(rootdir + self.path) #open requested file

                                #send code 200 response
                                self.send_response(200)

                                #send header first
                                self.send_header('Content-type','text-html')
                                self.end_headers()

                                #send file content to client
                                self.wfile.write(f.read())
                                f.close()
                                return

                except IOError:
                        self.send_error(404, 'file not found')

def run():
print('http server is starting...')

#ip and port of servr
#by default http server port is 80
server_address = ('127.0.0.1', 80)
httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, KodeFunHTTPRequestHandler)
print('http server is running...')
httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Write a simple HTTP client

To check if our server is working fine, we need an HTTP client. You can use your web browser to do this. But, It'll be cool if you make your own client. To accomplish this, let's make another script, let's name it kodefun-httpclient.py. Copy following script to your file:
kodefun-httpclient.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python (CLIENT CODE)

import httplib
import sys

#get http server ip
http_server = sys.argv[1]
#create a connection
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(http_server)

while 1:
            cmd = raw_input('input command (ex. GET index.html): ')
            cmd = cmd.split()

            if cmd[0] == 'exit': #tipe exit to end it
                        break

            #request command to server
            conn.request(cmd[0], cmd[1])


            #get response from server
            rsp = conn.getresponse()

            #print server response and data
            print(rsp.status, rsp.reason)
            data_received = rsp.read()
            print(data_received)

conn.close
```

Test using GET command